# Delphi XE2 host application from output directory

Tags: delphi, environment-variables, executable, delphi-xe2

Is there a way to tell a Delphi project that builds a DLL to use as a host application an executable in the same directory as the output directory of the DLL being built?

something like this:

[image: DLL host app Delphi - this does not work]

One thing is, I'm using option sets with Delphi XE2, so in the dproj for the DLL I'm building I don't even have a DCC_ExeOutput directory, not sure if that matters.

Allowing this would seriously decomplicate some issues we've ran into trying to migrate from VSS to SVN.

Also, what do you call the $(thing)'s?

Answer (score 4):

The `$(name)` things are environment variables. I tried setting the host application to `.\$(Platform)\$(Config)\Test.exe` and received this error message:

```
Could not find program, '.\%Platform%\%Config%\Test.exe'.
```

Note how the `$(...)` was turned into environment variable syntax.

I also tried with `$(systemdrive)\Test.exe` and received this error message:

```
Could not find program, 'C:\Test.exe'.
```

So clearly environment variables will be substituted with their values, if they do exist. I think it is reasonable to conclude that the environment used to start a host application clearly does not define the special Delphi specific environment variables.

So I think the answer to your question is that you cannot use indirection like this for the host application setting.

On the other hand, environment variables are substituted so perhaps you could use that to make things easier. In other words you could define some environment variables of your own. I've no idea whether that may be of help to you since I don't know the precise details of your problem.

Comment: Huh, well that all seems to be true, but you'd think I could set those with pre-link build events that MSBuild would run.  That way I could do something like `set outdir = ..\debug\final`.  that doesn't seem to want to work.  I could tell there was a difference between the Delphi environment variables and the Windows environment variables, it's just non-obvious when each of them can be invoked.

Comment: My mental model is that host app setting applies after build so all the build vars no longer apply. But that's just guesswork. And IDE plugin using toolsapi may reap rewards especially since we have proven that env vars are expanded.